# Is it possible to hide the header logo in the navbar but appears when scrolled down in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm kinda looking into something like [this](http://www.mikeanddave.co.nz) for the navbar where It's transparent on top but when scrolled it removes the transparency and the logo or the navbar brand name is shown.

Is there a way to do this for bootstrap? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: There are numerous bootstrap templates out there that would accomplish what you want. [Start here](https://www.google.com/#q=bootstrap+sticky+header+with+transition).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it getting the position of scroll top, and show or hide the image, something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/q3bz3dLu/).

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll > 30){
    $("#imgLogo").css("display", "inline");
  } else {
    $("#imgLogo").css("display", "none");
  }
});
```

And HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      <img id="imgLogo" src="https://getbootstrap.com/apple-touch-icon.png" width="40"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="body">
 Bottom
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about bootstrap, but since you have a javascript tag on your question I'll provide a javascript answer. :)

In the DOM add an event listener to the scroll event on the window object. Then whenever that event listener fires have it call a javascript function which has a conditional statement evaluating the scroll value. If it is anything but zero then remove transparency.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {

    var scrollY = window.scrollY,
        navbar = document.getElementById('navbar');

    if(scrollY > 0){
        navbar.style.opacity = "1";
    }
    else{
        navbar.style.opacity = "0";
    }

}
```

then in your css if you want a smooth transition just do this

```
#navbar{
    /*remember vendor prefixes for transition-duration!*/
    transition-duration: 5s;
}
```